# Sqlite database query based on a string name

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I created sqlite database inside my app and trying to save highlighted text , Saving is all working fine , even retrieving all highlights is working fine , but when I query for highlights based on bookname I am getting an error.

Here is what I tried so far - this is my `oncreate` of sqlite database:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HIGHLIGHTS + "("  
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +KEY_BOOKNAME +" TEXT," + KEY_HIGHLIGHT+" TEXT,"   + KEY_TEXTSIZE + " INTEGER,"  
            + KEY_PAGENO + " INTEGER" + ")";  
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);  
}
```

This is working fine

```
  public List<HighlightSave> getAllHighlights() {

    List<HighlightSave> saveAllHighlights=new ArrayList<HighlightSave>();

    String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_HIGHLIGHTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery( selectQuery,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        do {
            HighlightSave hs=new HighlightSave();
            hs.setBookName(cursor.getString(1));
            hs.setHighlightedText(cursor.getString(2));

            hs.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
            hs.setPageno(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));

            saveAllHighlights.add(hs);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return saveAllHighlights;
}
```

Problem is when I try to query using a bookname like below

```
 public List<HighlightSave> getBookHighlights(String bookname) {

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<HighlightSave> AllHighlightsOfBook= new ArrayList<HighlightSave>();

       Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_HIGHLIGHTS, new String[] {KEY_BOOKNAME,KEY_HIGHLIGHT,KEY_TEXTSIZE,KEY_PAGENO}, KEY_BOOKNAME + "=?", new String[] { bookname }, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{
            HighlightSave hs=new HighlightSave();
            hs.setBookName(cursor.getString(1));
            hs.setHighlightedText(cursor.getString(2));

            hs.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
            hs.setPageno(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));

            AllHighlightsOfBook.add(hs);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return AllHighlightsOfBook; 
}
```

I get this error

> 12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): Process: com.wowio.ebookreader, PID: 8811
>   12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
>
> 12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.eminosoft.epubreader.HighlightDatabase.getBookHighlights(HighlightDatabase.java:160)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.eminosoft.epubreader.HighlightFragment.onActivityCreated(HighlightFragment.java:66)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>       12-05 11:03:48.025: E/AndroidRuntime(8811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

so i thought some problem with cursor so initialised it this way inside getBookHighlights()

```
String query = "Select * from "+TABLE_HIGHLIGHTS+ " Where " +KEY_BOOKNAME + " = " + bookname ;
    Cursor cursor=  db.rawQuery(query,null);
```

then i am getting this error

```
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305): Process: com.wowio.ebookreader, PID: 12305
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Raven": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from highlights Where book_Name = The Raven
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at com.eminosoft.epubreader.HighlightDatabase.getBookHighlights(HighlightDatabase.java:146)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at com.eminosoft.epubreader.HighlightFragment.onActivityCreated(HighlightFragment.java:66)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-05 11:20:06.514: E/AndroidRuntime(12305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What am I doing wrong?  (I uninstalled app before every run so there won't be any problem with previous database)

Comment: are you testing on an emulator?

Comment: no onreal device nexus 6p

Comment: can you test on emulator for once? run your app and open sqlite db from adm and check if the table has data

Comment: emulator wont run on my pc

Comment: did you try genymotion?\

Comment: ya it gives some network error , even andy wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectify your **SELECT** query at first

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_HIGHLIGHTS+ " WHERE " + KEY_BOOKNAME + " = '" + bookname + "'";
```

Then **Uninstall old App and run Again** .

Answer (score 2):

The error regarding to fetch the column values.

Column index starts with the zero in the Sqlite cursor.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.`

So the meaning of the above line is 4 column is not available in the cursor object

Your try with 0 to 3. I think It should be resolved.

Comment: didn't try this answer ,because above answer worked fine so i am sticking to that any way thanks for help +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String query="select * from "+TABLE_HIGHLIGHTS+" where "+KEY_BOOKNAME+"='"+bookname+"'";
```

Comment: Thanks it works but, intellij answered it first so accepted his answer, any way +1 thanks for help :)

Comment: ya no proble.Thanks for +1